# Spring Framework: trying to add 301 redirect in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, servlets

I inherited a (poorly written) Java web app that has a bunch of URLs I need to change, but I don't want to break page rank for SEO purposes, so I'd like to make them automatically do a 301 redirect.  The app uses Spring for route mapping. I'm rather new to Spring and JavaEE, so please forgive any n00bness and help enlighten me. :-)

The app's routes are defined in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml` where they are mapped to the actual JSP's that handle each request. There are dozens and dozens of routes that need changing.  The configs look like this:

```
<bean id="urlMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="3" />
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/foo.html">fooController</prop>
            <prop key="/blah.html">barController</prop>
            ...
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Elsewhere in this file, their controllers are defined, such as:

```
<bean name="fooController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
    p:viewName="path/to/foo" />
<bean name="barController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
    p:viewName="path/to/bar" />
...
```

I'm thinking I should be able to edit these configs so that certain routes are given a 301 redirect to other routes, without having to resort to custom controllers or classes to handle the redirection.  I've been Googling and searching SO but I'm not finding it.  Is this possible? How?  Or what's the Best Practice(tm) for doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work because I never tried it, but maybe you can change the `p:viewName` value to `"redirect:/my/new/path"`. I think this might work since it is a valid view name.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks @Bart.  If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set a redirect statement as the viewName property. Any view name string that you would normally return from a handler (mapped controller method) should be valid.

```
<bean name="barController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
    p:viewName="redirect:/my/new/path" />
```

Comment: I discovered that if using Spring 3.0+, it also works to do this: `<mvc:view-controller path="some-path.html" view-name="redirect:/other-path.html"/>`.  Simpler than using `<bean>`.